# Cannot use database when loading data

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table adapter in C# that is loading data, this adapter is connected to a stored procedure that is loading data from SQL view.
The problem is when this adapter is fetching data, no other user can use the rest of the system! (example i cannot log in)even on another PC  and a message (timeout expired) is thrown, until the adapter finishes it's work!

The adapter's SQL statement (selecting from a view) :

```sql
select * from vw_MyView where Date>=@from and Date<=@to
```

Any ideas?!

Comment: how big is your data, and how many records are you fetching?

Comment: Yeah. Read up on threading. Read up on background worker. Do not block the UI during long operations (regardless what they are).

Comment: the view may contains 40000 records.

Comment: I cannot login even using another pc.. and a message (timeout expired is thrown)

Comment: Are you debugging by any chance?

Comment: @SmartDev if you mean breakpoints then no.

Comment: looks like your server cannot handle the operations. there might be a hardware issue here.

Comment: no hardware issues , because i checked it on 2 servers, I guess there is a lock done somewhere(but my code has no lock),I discarded the adapter and used a function that calls the store procedure same issue !

Comment: Show us the SQL that you are using to fetch the data

Comment: @BerndLinde select * from vw_MyView where Date>=@from and Date<=@to
Just this .(selecting from a view)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? If MSSQL, is your database not maybe in SingleUser mode?  Please also update the question with your code, don't put code into comments since it makes it harder to read, also if you can include the view's code aswell

Comment: do you by chance require to retrieve all records and columns? I mean why dont you use Top N and column names instead of *? Hope you do not require to bind all 40K records at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it!
I added

> `With (noLock)`

in front of each table. for example :

> Select * from table1 with (nolock ) inner join table2 with (noLock) on table1.ID = table2.ID

Note the `With (NoLock)` in front of each table I want not to lock.

Thanks all for your efforts!

Answer (score -2):

If i understood you well, you should use the below and it would keep your application running normally while the adapter is fetching data.

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

Comment: This is just a bandaid to hide the real problem. Either do things in additional Threads or figure out why it is running slow